# Takes forever to login?

Tags: 10.04, login-screen, gdm

After upgrading to 10.04, Ubuntu takes a long time (1-2 minutes) to login after typing the credentials. The majority of this time the dialog box says "checking credentials". How do I even go about debugging what is going on here? This is a very snappy system, but apparently something is hanging or not responding during the login.

Here's my :0-greeter.log. Any ideas?

```
Window manager warning: Failed to read saved session file /var/lib/gdm/.config/metacity/sessions/1046b54d5b8b97fbb2128498129581685800000016580008.ms: Failed to open file '/var/lib/gdm/.config/metacity/sessions/1046b54d5b8b97fbb2128498129581685800000016580008.ms': No such file or directory
** (process:1742): DEBUG: Greeter session pid=1742 display=:0.0 xauthority=/var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-pWDXxn/database

(gnome-power-manager:1745): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.24.1/gobject/gsignal.c:2273: signal `proxy-status' is invalid for instance `0x21f5160'

** (gnome-power-manager:1745): WARNING **: Either HAL or DBUS are not working!

** (gnome-power-manager:1745): WARNING **: proxy failed

** (gnome-power-manager:1745): WARNING **: failed to get Computer root object

** (gnome-power-manager:1745): WARNING **: proxy NULL!!
gdm-simple-greeter[1742]: Gtk-WARNING: /build/buildd/gtk+2.0-2.20.1/gtk/gtkwidget.c:5636: widget not within a GtkWindow
Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0xe00046 (Login Wind)
Window manager warning: meta_window_activate called by a pager with a 0 timestamp; the pager needs to be fixed.
Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0xe00046 (Login Wind)
Window manager warning: meta_window_activate called by a pager with a 0 timestamp; the pager needs to be fixed.

(gnome-settings-daemon:1666): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_thaw_toplevel_updates_libgtk_only: assertion `private->update_and_descendants_freeze_count > 0' failed
Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0xe00046 (Login Wind)
Window manager warning: meta_window_activate called by a pager with a 0 timestamp; the pager needs to be fixed.
Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
Window manager warning: Got a request to focus the no_focus_window with a timestamp of 0.  This shouldn't happen!

(gnome-power-manager:1745): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some great tips here, and I wish I could do more than just upvote. However, the real problem which I discovered thanks to msw, was this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/584428

To solve it, I commented out this line in /etc/pam.d/common-auth

```
auth optional pam_smbpass.so migrate
```

I don't understand why this causes problems; I never used samba for login authentication on this machine.

Comment: +1: self answers are good for StackOverflow (and glad you found the trouble)

Answer (score 4):

"HAL or DBUS not working" is to Gnome as "fuel pump not working" is to car, or at least close. gnome-power-manager isn't causing your problem, but its complaint is pretty good indication of what is. There are two prongs to the answer:

### save the world

This is "should not happen" and if it has happened to you on an Ubuntu LTS upgrade, it likely has or will happen to someone else and Ubuntu wants to know about it. The command to use is

```
$ ubuntu-bug gdm
```

as documented at [Reporting Bugs - HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Filing%20a%20bug%20with%20ubuntu-bug).

### save yourself

There was a time when I could claim detailed knowledge of the Unix process hierarchy and initialization routines; no longer. I find the dbus system quite mystical, and have to resort to:

1. extended, detailed, painful debug sessions, or
2. use the Microsoft "Nuke it from Orbit Approach to System Administration"®

Across this bandwidth limited channel, I'd recommend (2) and:

- log in on the console <kbd>Ctrl-Alt</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd>
- nuke gdm, dbus and relations with `sudo apt-get purge gdm dbus dbus-x11`
- reboot
- from the console reinstall gdm and dbus with `sudo apt-get install gdm dbus dbus-x11`
- reboot
- compute in blissful harmony

Good luck.

Comment: This wasn't the problem, but your answer led me to the solution. When I logged into the console, it timed out, and searching for that error message led me to the real problem. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 3):

As a start, try perusing `/var/log/gdm/:0-greeter.log`. See if you can spot the delay by following the timestamps in `/var/log/auth.log`.

Comment: I've tried this, but I don't see anything that looks suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

Idea #1: Sounds like it could be DNS-timeout related perhaps?

- Verify your network settings, and make sure you can ping any DNS servers listed in `/etc/resolv.conf`.
- Try doing some things that will resolve names to IPs, like `ping www.google.com`

If they don't work, or take a long time, that could be the issue.

Idea #2: Is this machine using something external - like LDAP or NIS or something - for auth credentials? If so, it could be waiting on response from that external machine.